# replacing a specific value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  item=c("a","","a","d","e"),
  price_today=c(1,2,"THREE%%",4,"SIX/SIX"))
```

If I would like to select "THREE%%" and "SIX/SIX" in column `price_today` and convert them to "3?3" and "6?6", respectively, how should I go about it?

Comment: `df$price_today[df$price_today == "THREE%%"] <- "3?3"`

Comment: Working Perfectly now, thanks Maël